# AWS IVS: closed captioning into aws IVS channel into ReactJS component

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, video.js, amazon-ivs

I have managed to load the `aws IVS` streaming channel into `video tag`. Now I need to display the closed caption feature as well. But it is not displaying any `closed captioning` while clicking on the captions button.

```js
function IVSComponent(options) {
  const divEl = useRef(null);
  const videoEl = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');

    script.src = 'https://player.live-video.net/1.0.0/amazon-ivs-player.min.js';
    script.async = true;

    document.body.appendChild(script);

    script.onload = () => {
      if (IVSPlayer.isPlayerSupported) {
        const player = IVSPlayer.create();
        player.attachHTMLVideoElement(document.getElementById('video-player'));
        player.load("https://fcc3ddae59ed.us-west-2.playback.live-video.net/api/video/v1/us-west-2.893648527354.channel.xhP3ExfcX8ON.m3u8");
        player.play();
      }
    }

    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    }

  },[])
  
  return (
    <div ref={divEl}>
      <video id="video-player" x-webkit-airplay="allow" ref={videoEl} playsInline autoPlay controls>
      <track label="English" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="https://video-react.js.org/assets/elephantsdream/captions.en.vtt" default />
      <track label="Deutsch" kind="subtitles" srclang="de" src="https://video-react.js.org/assets/elephantsdream/captions.en.vtt" />
      <track label="Español" kind="subtitles" srclang="es" src="https://video-react.js.org/assets/elephantsdream/captions.en.vtt"></track>
      </video>
    </div>
  );

}

export default IVSComponent;
```

[image]